# How to convert flat list to the tree

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<root>
    <Element1>
       <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
       <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
       <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
       <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
    </Element1>
    <AnotherElement>
         <YetAnotherElement>
            <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
            <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
            <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
            <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
         </YetAnotherElement>
    </AnotherElement>
</root>
```

How to convert 'Hierarchy' messages into tree? i.e.

```
<root>
    <Element1>
       <Hierarchy attr="value">
         <Hierarchy attr="value">
           <Hierarchy attr="value">
             <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
           </Hierarchy>
         </Hierarchy>
       </Hierarchy>
    </Element1>
    <AnotherElement>
         <YetAnotherElement>
            <Hierarchy attr="value">
               <Hierarchy attr="value">
                  <Hierarchy attr="value">
                     <Hierarchy attr="value"/>
                  </Hierarchy>
               </Hierarchy>
            </Hierarchy>
         </YetAnotherElement>
    </AnotherElement>
</root>
```

Comment: Are you just interested in the indenting? Most editors/generators will put elements at the same depth into the same columns for readability, because as far as the document model is concerned, they're on the same level. If it is the indenting you're worried about, it might help to provide the editor you're using, or the generator that's creating this XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Hierarchy[position() != 1]"/>
    <xsl:template match="Hierarchy[1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="Hierarchy"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Hierarchy" mode="Hierarchy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Hierarchy[1]" mode="Hierarchy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<root>
    <Element1>
        <Hierarchy attr="value">
            <Hierarchy attr="value">
                <Hierarchy attr="value">
                    <Hierarchy attr="value"></Hierarchy>
                </Hierarchy>
            </Hierarchy>
        </Hierarchy>
    </Element1>
    <AnotherElement>
        <YetAnotherElement>
            <Hierarchy attr="value">
                <Hierarchy attr="value">
                    <Hierarchy attr="value">
                        <Hierarchy attr="value"></Hierarchy>
                    </Hierarchy>
                </Hierarchy>
            </Hierarchy>
        </YetAnotherElement>
    </AnotherElement>
</root>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: +1. That really is an achievement, ja!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:if test="name() != 'Hierarchy'">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Hierarchy">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:call-template name="makeTree">
        <xsl:with-param name="elem" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="makeTree">
    <xsl:param name="elem" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$elem/@*" />
      <xsl:if test="count($elem/following-sibling::node()) > 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="makeTree">
          <xsl:with-param name="elem" select="$elem/following-sibling::node()[1]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```